# Extending/patching HTMLScriptElement.prototype.attributes

Tags: javascript, dom

The actual problem I am trying to solve is preventing execution of dynamically added scripts, and I don't know of an other way than modifying the `type` and `src` attributes to do this. I assumed patching `document.createElement()` would be even more problematic.

So, I'm trying to modify the attributes property of the HTMLScriptElement.prototype object in order to replace some provided attributes in a custom `get attributes` property when the element is created. The idea is to modify the script object for this purpose rather than changing `document.createElement()` with an equivalent patch. I don't have access to or knowledge of added scripts or HTML. You can assume that my code can run before any other scripts, if that should be needed.

My first thought was to reassign `attributes` with my custom implementation, but that apparently requires to setup a Live Node List, which I can not find information about. Without a Live Node List, the HTML-element-attributes are not updated, which is however required.

Is there a way to extend the existing `get attributes` property to edit the attributes at object creation? Attributes need to be replaced before the script is added to the document. I know that I can use a MutationObserver for existing scripts, but I read that this won't work for dynamically added scripts.

Comment: If you don't even have knowledge of HTML, how do you expect to do anything at all, regarding web development? You should also learn  CSS and JavaScript. You shouldn't waste your time changing things you don't understand.

Comment: [Don't modify the DOM prototypes!](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) Apart from that, your approach will not even work - providing some getters or setters on the prototype will not change anything about how the browser internally constructs the element. You need to focus on the way that the element is actually created and added to the DOM - if by a call to `document.createElement()`, then that's your best bet, if not, you're probably out of control.

Comment: @StackSlave I understood "*I don't have access to or knowledge of added scripts or HTML*" as that he has no control over the html of the page in which is his script is loaded. Not that he knows nothing about web development.

Comment: "*in order to replace some provided attributes*" - what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) that you're trying to solve by that?

Comment: @StackSlave Read again -- the sentence was about the added scripts. I could have explained that I meant the HTML of the site which I do not have control over, but thought it was clear enough...

Comment: Here's what I read: `"I don't have access to or knowledge of added scripts or HTML."`

Comment: @Bergi I know that what I want to do is considered bad. The actual problem I am trying to solve is preventing execution of dynamically added scripts, and I don't know of an other way than modifying the `type` and `src` attributes to do this. I assumed patching document.createElement() would be even more problematic.

Comment: @matjaeck Ah. Well, for that purpose you rather should use [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) which blocks any script execution that isn't whitelisted.

Comment: If that was your actual reason for asking then why didn't you say so in your initial post? How can you expect people to answer a question when you fail to give the full story?

Comment: @matjaeck And yes, even monkey-patching `document.createElement` would likely not have worked (at least in all cases), as there are many ways to dynamically add scripts to a page that don't involve `createElement`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, but that probably won't work for me. I don't want to go into detail since the question was really just about what the title says. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @JK I am pretty sure that it would have been marked as a duplicate then or that I would have had to deal with "Be more specific." type of comments. My question was exactly about what I have written.

Comment: What mechanism/code is dynamically adding the scripts in the first place?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is there a way to extend the existing `get attributes` property to edit the attributes at object creation?

No. The `attributes` getter of the JS representation is not used during DOM object creation.